# Count the no of times an image is pressed/tapped

Tags: c++, qt

I want to count the no of times an image is pressed. Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: How are you displaying your image?

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g. subclass [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) and reimplement [QLabel::mousePressEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent). Or you write an [eventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) which catches mouse events on the QLabel.